# React Leaflet v3 : Good way to create a control

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I'm displaying a map with react leaflet v3 in my react app.

I just want to add a custom control, but I can't figure out what's the good way to do that.

Actually, i do it like that, but it seems to be not working.

```js
function DptCtl(props) {
    // Control
    const map = useMap();

    // List of dpts and provinces
    const dpts = useSelector(dptsSelector);

    L.Control.Dpts = L.Control.extend({
        onAdd(map) {
            const container = L.DomUtil.create('div');
            const input = L.DomUtil.create('input', container);

            
            return container;
        },
        onRemove(map) {}
    })

    L.Control.dpts = function (opts) {
        return new L.Control.Dpts(opts);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const control = L.Control.dpts({ position: props.position })
        map.addControl(control)

        return () => {
            map.removeControl(control)
        }
    }, [dpts])

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React-Leaflet v3 provides the [createControlComponent](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#createcontrolcomponent) Hook in the [Core API](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#) that takes in an instance of a Leaflet control and returns a Leaflet element.

Here is an example using Leaflet's Zoom control:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import { createControlComponent } from '@react-leaflet/core';

const createControlLayer = (props) => {
  // Set up an instance of the control:
  const controlInstance = new L.Control.Zoom(props);

  return controlInstance;
};

// Pass the control instance to the React-Leaflet createControlComponent hook:
const customControl = createControlComponent(createControlLayer);

export default customControl;
```

Then, add the new custom control layer to the Map:

```
<MapContainer
  center={[37.0902, -95.7129]}
  zoom={3}
  zoomControl={false}
  style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%', padding: 0 }}
  whenCreated={(map) => setMap(map)}
>
  <CustomControl />
  <LayersControl position="topright">
    <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="Map">
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url={maps.base}
      />
    </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
  </LayersControl>
</MapContainer>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6m54zs?file=src%2FMyMap.jsx,src%2FApp.js,public%2Findex.html,src%2FCustomZoomControl.jsx)

- https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-api/#createcontrolcomponent
- https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-create-a-react-leaflet-control-component-with-leaflet-routing-machine-8eef98259f20